# Giving dimension names to array along the largest dimension

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I want to create a growing matrix with dimension names.

I use the following code:

```
completeMatrix = matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:3){
  newMatrix <- matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
  completeMatrix <- abind(completeMatrix, newMatrix , along = 3)
```

}

I want completeMatrix to have dimnames along its third dimension, by giving a name to each "newMatrix".

Eventually i want something like this:

```
completeMatrix = matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:3){
  newMatrix <- matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
  dimnames(newMatrix) <- "MatrixName"
  completeMatrix <- abind(completeMatrix, newMatrix , along = 3)
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(30),6,5)
y <- matrix(rnorm(30),6,5)
abind(x=x,y=y,along = 3)
```

Comment: What if i want the matrix names to be different? for example i have a string name str <- "name of matrix". and i want x to be named according to the value of str. i.e. something like abind(x=str,y=y, along=3)

Comment: you can name the objects as you like. In this example you gave, it is just reversed. It sould work with `abind(str=x,y=y, along=3)`